# How can you solve this in Python? Automatically supply an argument to a static method when called from a managing class

Tags: python, oop, static-methods

I have some classes `FooA` and `FooB` which are basically a collection of "static" methods. They operate on `data` - let's say it is an `DataItem` object:

```py
# Base class with common behavior
class FooBase:
    @classmethod
    def method1(cls, arg, data: DataItem):
        #res = ...
        return res
    
    @classmethod
    def method2(cls, arg1, arg2, data: DataItem):
        # res = ... # using method1
        return res

# specialized classes
class FooA(FooBase):
    # define extra methods
    pass
    
class FooB(FooBase):
    # define extra methods
    pass


# usage 1: as "static methods"
res = FooA.method1(arg, data)
res2 = FooB.method2(args, data)
```

Now, I'd like to use these classes as attributes of a "managing" class (`MyApp`) which also has access to a `datasource` and should implicitly supply `DataItems` to the static methods of `FooA` and `FooB`. Moreover, the `datasource` supplies a list of `DataItem` objects.

```py
# usage 2: as part of an "App" class
# here, the "data" argument should be supplied implicitly by MyApp
# also: MyApp contains a list of "data" objects 
class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, datasrc):
        self.datasrc = datasrc
    
    # this could be a generator
    def get_data(self, key) -> List[DataItem]: 
        return self.datasrc.get_data(key)
        
    # FooA, FooB as class / instance level attributes, descriptors, ???
    
    
# usage
my_app = MyApp("datasrc")
res_list = my_app.foo_a.method1(arg)   # foo_a is a FooA obj, "data" arg is supplied automatically 

# optionally, but not necessarily call as a static attribute:
res = MyApp.foo_a.method1(arg, data: DataItem)   # same as FooA.method1(arg, data)
```

I have tried different things but found not satisfactory solution.

Comment: Is something that stops you from passing data to `FooBase` constructor?

Comment: @kosciej16 - no, not really. I originally wanted for `foo_a` or `foo_b` to be also accessible as static attributes of `MyApp` - like in: `MyApp.foo_a.method1()`. But that is not a necessity. What I'd like to know is how I can make it so that I can call `my_app.foo_a.method1(arg)` which internally translates to something like `[FooA.method1(arg, data) for data in self.get_data()]`.

Comment: Got it! I have few ideas, will write them at the evening ;)

Answer (score 0):

So... I am not sure can it be done in nice way, I thought about that and all approaches has serious drawbacks. One of the problem is we actually want to have a method that returns list or single item, depending on input parameters, which is bad.

One of way could be store `datasrc` in FooBase, but it violates [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)

```
class FooBase:
    def __init__(self, datasrc):
        FooBase.datasrc = datasrc

    @classmethod
    def method1(cls, arg, data=None):
        if data is None:
            return [cls.method1(arg, d) for d in cls.datasrc]
        return data
```

Or use `isinstance`

```
    @classmethod
    def method1(cls, arg, data):
        if isinstance(data, list):
            return [cls.method1(arg, d) for d in data]
        return data
```

But it forces us to adjust every method (which could be done with decorator or metaclass).

Another way could be use some intermediate layer:

```
def decorator(datasrc):
    def wrapper(foo):
        def f(*args, **kwargs):
            # We could catch TypeError here to serve case when data is passed
            return [foo(*args, **kwargs, data=data) for data in datasrc]

        return f

    return wrapper


class FooAdapter:
    def __init__(self, datasrc, foo_cls):
        self.datasrc = datasrc
        methods = [
            getattr(foo_cls, m)
            for m in dir(foo_cls)
            if callable(getattr(foo_cls, m)) and not m.startswith("__")
        ] # all methods of our Foo class
        for method in methods:
            setattr(self, method.__name__, decorator(datasrc)(method))

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, datasrc):
        self.datasrc = datasrc
        self.foo_a = FooAdapter(datasrc, FooA)
        self.foo_b = FooAdapter(datasrc, FooB)
```

But solution with dynamically added functions breaks IDE support.

The cleanest solution imo could be to have `Enum` for `Foo` methods and `Enum` for `Foo` classes, then you could write code in MyApp

```
def get_bulk(m: MethodEnum, f: FooEnum, *args):
    return [getattr(enum_to_cls_mapping[f], m)(*args, data=d) for d in self.datasrc]
```

Comment: @koscief16 - thanks. I will later try your example with the adapter and report back.

Comment: @YettiMG Did later come? ;)

Comment: I dropped the original idea as it was too convoluted. Anyway, I found this nice library which I'm now looking into for my simulation and interactive visualization projects: https://param.holoviz.org/index.html